# How do I change date/time format on object? To 24 hour clock

Tags: lightning, datetime, format

[image]
Every objects I have, the date/time format is in 24 hour clock. So why is there this object with am/pm? How do I change it to 24 hour clock format?

The weird thing is that when I edit the field. It is shown in 24 hour format
[image]

Comment: Hi @Rasmus , I have deleted my answer as it is not related now as you added additional information on the question. I  am able to replicate same in my org and working on this with internal team on this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know when you find a fix for it. :))

Comment: Sure. Thank you

Comment: This is generally related to the locale of the user, though I am unsure why display and editing vary for you.

Comment: @PhilW, Actually the locale is supporting 24 hour format. But this is showing 12 hour format in shift start and end dates. It is working fine in list view and edit. But not working on record view.

Comment: Is this in the standard record page or is this using a `lightning-record-form`/`lightning-record-edit-form`?

Comment: (Please add extra detail in the question via [edit])

Comment: This is just the standard layout and no customisations for the same. I am trying to check this internally with product team on this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on my above comments I have Checked this internally with product team and a new bug (W-12037262) has been logged from Salesforce Side for the same.

This is working as expected in Classic, in  lightning list views and Lightning Edit  page as well. The issue seems to be only while viewing the record from Record page.

Comment: Great. So is it supposed to be fixed soon?

Comment: @Rasmus, As of now this is not prioritised for next release. This will be fixed in future releases